# Why this program with for loop give zero when y>5 and x=2

Tags: java

whenever I give x =2 and y>5 the result is zero. for any other value it's ok..

```
package forLoopquestionsForForLoop;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalculatexXPowerY {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter X");
    long x = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter y");
    long y = sc.nextInt();
    int power = 1;
    for(int i =0;i<y;i++) {
      x *= x;
    }
    System.out.println(x);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the post and format the code properly.

Comment: When I run your code and enter 2 and 5, I get `4294967296` instead of 0. This is what I'd expect since 2*2=4, 4*4=16, 16*16=256, 256*256=65536, and 65536*65536=4294967296

Comment: i have said for y>6 not for y=6

Comment: You can't go greater than 5 cause you would exceed the max value a Long can hold.

Comment: Try to do it on paper. What value should you get for x for y>6 lets say 7? What is max value of `long`?

Comment: @TimHunter  no.. but try for x = 3 and y = 6..it should also be exceeding the long max value ..but its giving the result..

Comment: @Pshemo   check it for x = 3 and y = 6..it will give result

Comment: @VMS That's a misunderstanding due to [overflow](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Java-overflow-and-underflow). The values you're getting for that aren't actually the full amount, only the partial that's able to fit.

Comment: @VMS You didn't answer my question.

Comment: @TimHunter  so why it's not happening with x = 2 and y = 6 ..it should also give partial result but it's not giving that instead it returns 0

Comment: @VMS It has to do with overflow. Your `4294967296 * 4294967296` from `y=6` rolls over from the max value, which turns to zero because you hit exactly +1 over the max. From that point on, every multiplication is `0 * 0` as far as the system can tell.

Comment: @Pshemo yaa it will exceed the max value of long ...long max value will be from -2^63 to (2^63)-1 or (2^64)-1 depending whether its signed or unassigned

Comment: @TimHunter okk..but just one question why it's not the case with x = 3 and y = 6

Comment: For x=3 after each iterations it will become 9, 81, 6561, 43046721, -501334399, 2038349057. Notice that overflowing doesn't mean that *all* bytes will be reset to 0, but that exceeding bytes will be ignored.

Comment: @VMS Because that multiplication doesn't roll over the maximum right at the edge of the max long value. The 2 value rolls over at just the right value that when it cuts off all the overflowing bits the system reads it as 000000000000... The others exceed it so there's left over bits and thus has something to keep multiplying.

Comment: @TimHunter  oh thanks ... I got u..u solved my problem man!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have some time, so I figured I'd come back and give a more proper explanation of what is happening. Your `long` variable is represented in the system as a series of bits, 64 of them in fact, which can contain either 0 or 1 as their value. They can be visualized like so:

```
0000 0000 0000 0010 0000 0000 1100 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100
```

Having all 0's translates to the value zero and the front most bit is reserved for special usage as a marker for whether the number is positive or negative. This means the maximum positive value you can have is 2^63-1 which ~9.22 e+18.

Now, when you [multiply these bits](https://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-multiplication/) they essentially shift over a certain number of spots before adding themselves. This can lead to unexpected behavior called [overflow](https://www.baeldung.com/java-overflow-underflow) which pushes the calculated value over the maximum size of it's variable container. When this happens, the system can no longer track the bits that exceed the sequence and essentially "forgets" about them. Lets look at a 4 bit example:

```
     1111  (15)
x    0011   (3)
---------
     1111  (15)
+   11110  (30)
+  000000   (0)
+ 0000000   (0)
---------
  0101101  (45)
```

The value `0101101` exceeds our 4 bits though, so the system "forgets" about the bits that exceed the 4 and turns into `1101` instead. This is what is happening with your zeroing out problem. Yours is an interesting case though because with the value `4294967296` you're essentially performing:

```
    0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
x   0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

And then because the foremost `1` is greater than the maximum bits for a `long` it is "forgot" which leaves only `0` as the value. After that, every multiplication is doing `0 x 0` over and over. Hope this answers your question more completely.

Comment: ok i got u ... due to some reason i can't post question  for 1 day but i have one more doubt in different program its a very small doubtso here i am getting resource leak warning but when i close it in for loop i dont get any warning so why it is so      program is :-

package forLoop;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BreakStatement {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int m =sc.nextInt();
  for(;;)
  {
   System.out.println(m--);
   if(m<1)
    break;
   
  }
  sc.close();
 
 }
}
just copy paste it you will get clear prgm

Comment: @VMS That's because your break is after an infinite `for` loop. The compiler doesn't assume that it will ever reach the close statement when there's an infinite `for` loop cause there's no guarantee it ever will. That's why it gives a warning. Switch your `for(;;)` loop to a regular one or a `while(true)` version and the warning will disappear. As for why `for(;;)` infinites flag this but `while(true)` does not, you will have to ask someone more familiar with Java under the hood than me.

Comment: @VMS You can also make the warning disappear by moving the `sc.close()` inside your `if` check like so: `if(m < 1) { sc.close(); break; }`

Answer (score 0):

You are exceeding the max value of Long, when you assign values x = 2 and y > 5.
You can use BigInteger instead.

```
import java.math.BigInteger; 
BigInteger result = new BigInteger("1");
for(int i =0;i<y;i++)
{
 result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(x));
    
}
System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: but i dont want to use maths class. however my question is solved..thanks btw